# Angular global factory

Tags: angularjs

I created a factory that I would like to use in different pages:

```
var sessionApp = angular.module('sessionApp', ['LocalStorageModule']);

sessionApp.config(function(localStorageServiceProvider)
{
localStorageServiceProvider
    .setPrefix('mystorage')
    .setStorageType('localStorage');

});

sessionApp.factory('SessionFactory', function(localStorageService)
{
var service = {};
var _store = 'session';

service.load = function()
{
    var session = localStorageService.get(_store);
}

service.save = function(data)
{
    localStorageService.set(_store, JSON.stringify(data));
}

service.delete = function()
{
    localStorageService.remove(_store);
}

return service; 
});
```

Then I would add it on apps run method where I would assign it to the $rootScope.  I left that part of the code commented out for now.

```
var loginApp = angular.module("loginApp", []);

loginApp.run(function($rootScope, SessionFactory)
{
//$rootScope.sessionFactory = SessionFactory;

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',
function(ev, next, current)
{

});     
});
```

My error is:

> Unknown provider: SessionFactoryProvider <- SessionFactory

Is it because my factory is from sessionApp and my login module is loginApp?  Does that mean that I need to have the variables named the same like below:

File: login.js

```
var myApp = angular.module("loginApp", []);

myApp.run(function($rootScope, SessionFactory)
{
//$rootScope.sessionFactory = SessionFactory;

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',
function(ev, next, current)
{

});     
});
```

File: session.js

```
myApp.config(function(localStorageServiceProvider)
{
localStorageServiceProvider
    .setPrefix('mystorage')
    .setStorageType('localStorage');

});

myApp.factory('SessionFactory', function(localStorageService)
{
var service = {};
var _store = 'session';

service.load = function()
{
    var session = localStorageService.get(_store);
}

service.save = function(data)
{
    localStorageService.set(_store, JSON.stringify(data));
}

service.delete = function()
{
    localStorageService.remove(_store);
}

return service; 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array argument to angular.module is an array of other modules that you new module depends on. `loginApp` needs to list `sessionApp` as a dependency.

```
var loginApp = angular.module("loginApp", ["sessionApp"]);
```